# Get value of out parameter before assigning

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, parameters, out, param

I'm updating a method that contains an out parameter. I need to check the value of the parameter before setting it to a default.

```
public int DoWork(out int param)
{
    param = 0;
}
```

However, when I try to do something like this

```
public int DoWork(out int param)
{
    if(param == 8)
        param = 0;
}
```

I get an error saying **"Use of unassigned out parameter 'param'"**.

Is there a way I can use the value passed to the method before assigning it?

**UPDATE: I cannot use the ref keyword. A lot of code would break and it's not part of the design**

Comment: You must use keyword ref

Comment: I think you are confused about what the out keyword does. Maybe you meant to use `ref`?

Comment: You may use `ref` parameter instead

Comment: I can't change it to ref. A lot of other code would break.

Comment: I just pushed an update. I can't be using ref, so I guess I'm kinda screwed. but thanks for the info :)

Comment: You cannot do this. An "out" parameter _has_ no value before it's assigned, even if you assigned one before calling the method.

Comment: @miguelarcilla You may hack it by invoking something like **pointer**, but i don't approve such things ;)

Comment: No that won't work, [an `out` parameter](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html#out) must be initalized in the method not before. So you cannot read it before you assign a value in the method. So you need a `ref` even if that means a lot of redesign. Why do you need to check it at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can if you really need and want to cheat. Here's the sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace Test774
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = 666;
            DoWork(out a);
        }

        public static int DoWork(out int param)
        {
            var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("ParameterExtractor", typeof(int), new [] { typeof(int).MakeByRefType() });
            var generator = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldind_I4);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            var parameterExtractor = (MethodWithTheOutParameter)dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(MethodWithTheOutParameter), null);
            Console.WriteLine(parameterExtractor(out param));
            param = 1;
            return 0;
        }

        public delegate int MethodWithTheOutParameter(out int a);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a good answer. If the value is not assigned it will give you 0.

Comment: I don't see the big warning sign that doing this is a very bad idea :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use "ref" keyword instead of "out".

"Out" specifically means that the parameter is initialized and assigned in the method, with no need to initalize it before, and so compiler assume that the parameter is just declared but has no value.

"Ref", instead, does exactly what you are looking for.

```
public int DoWork(ref int param)
{
    if(param == 8)
        param = 0;
}

//your code:
int val = 5;
DoWork(ref val);
val.ToString(); // outputs 5
val = 8;
DoWork(ref val);
val.ToString(); // outputs 0
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not allowed to change it. It would break a lot of things if I did

Comment: Then no, you can't get the value. The out keyword doesn't work like that, out are just used to output values from the function. Ref is what you use if you need the value then want to update it.

Comment: You simply can't do what you want to do, by design.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the heads-up, I guess I'll have to find another way around it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ref` keyword.

```
public int DoWork(ref int param)
{
    if(param == 8)
        param = 0;
}
```

This way you can assign a new value to your param but also use the old one. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/14akc2c7.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can use the value passed to the method before assigning it?

No, there isn't, and it does not have a value anyway (either zero or garbage).